# jQuery TypeError: a.style is undefined when loading svg file in Firefox 20.0

Tags: jquery, firefox, svg

I work with SVG file. SVG file has xlink-ed jQuery.

When opening svg file in Firefox 20.0 I get error

> TypeError: a.style is undefined

If I open svg file in Firefox 19 and older versions, no errors appears.

Any ideas why jQuery with svg is not working in FF20.0?

My SVG demo file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="467" height="462">

  <rect x="80" y="60" width="250" height="250" rx="20"
      style="fill:#ff0000; stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2px;" />

  <rect x="140" y="120" width="250" height="250" rx="40"
      style="fill:#0000ff; stroke:#000000; stroke-width:2px;
      fill-opacity:0.7;" />

  <script
     xlink:href="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"
     id="script10"
     type="text/javascript" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Same problem with jQuery 1.7.1, 1.8.x, and 1.9.1 + svg.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to jQuery assuming it's running in an HTML document, basically.  See http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13754

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Boris in the other answer, this is due by a jquery bug.

In [this link](https://support.mozilla.org/questions/955772) you can see more information about it.

One of the comments suggests the following (in jquery-1.9.1):

In jquery-1.9.1, line 1321, **change from** this:

```
if ( !all || !a || !all.length ) {
```

**To** this:

```
if (!all || !a || !all.length || !a.style) {
```

His explanation:

> This should cause the jQuery.support function to return {} (an empty
>   object), as it seems to do on other browsers. In FF19, "!a" evaluates
>   to true. In FF20 "!a" evaluates to false, but a.style is undefined. So
>   checking for !a.style should avoid the error here.

This has solved my problem!

**Note**: It's not a good practice to change third-party code, but I didn't find any better solution by now.